# Pandas. pd.read_csv KeyError:not in index error

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I'm working with CSV file with over million entries. I'm trying to read data for each candidate as a separate column. I was able to parse data for the first candidate but when I get to next candidate I'm getting error ['cand_nm'] not in index.

Here is the link to file: [Link to data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5QNBpFZ7Ie2U3ExN3ZCNWIyeFE/view?usp=sharing)

```
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

## First candidate

```
reader_bachmann = pd.read_csv('P00000001-ALL.csv', squeeze=True, low_memory=False, nrows=411 )
print(reader_bachmann)
cand_bachmann = reader_bachmann[["cand_nm"]] 
print(cand_bachmann)
```

## Second candidate

```
reader_romney = pd.read_csv('P00000001-ALL.csv', skiprows=range(0,411) ,  na_filter =True, low_memory=False)
print(reader_romney)
cand_romney = reader_romney[["cand_nm"]] 
print(cand_romney)
```

## Error message

```
KeyError: "['cand_nm'] not in index"
```

Comment: Is the first row the headers? It seems your `skiprows=range(0,411)` would have skipped the headers, causing 'cand_nm' to be undefined index

Comment: Thank you. It fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `skip_rows` like that you lose the header. So you header for `reader_romney` is now row number 412. If this is the way you want to read the file you will need to store the header line to a list of strings and then pass that list as the `names=` kwarg. For example

```
r_bachman = pd.read_csv('P00000001-ALL.csv', squeeze=True, low_memory=False,
                        nrows=411 )
cols = r_bachman.columns
r_romney = pd.read_csv('P00000001-ALL.csv', skiprows=range(0,411),
                       na_filter =True, low_memory=False, names=cols)
```

Comment: Thank you. It fixed the problem.